# UE4 C++ APlayerController::GetHUD always return null

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Here is my code.

```
void AFpsCharacter::ClientRPCInitializeHud_Implementation()
 {
     AFpsPlayerController* PlayerController = (AFpsPlayerController*)GetOwner();
     if (IsValid(PlayerController))
     {
         AFpsPlayerState* State = PlayerController->GetPlayerState<AFpsPlayerState>();
         UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("PlayerController now on %s"), *State->GetPlayerName());
         HUD = (AFpsHud*)PlayerController->GetHUD(); //AHUD* HUD in AFpsCharacter.
         //HUD = Cast<AFpsHud>(PlayerController->GetHUD());
         if (!IsValid(HUD))
         {
             UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("AFpsCharacter::InitializeHud() : HUD is not valid"));
         }
     }
     else
     {
         UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("PlayerController is not exist"));
     }
 }
```

The function `ClientRPCInitializeHud()` is run when the character is spawned and `PlayerController` possess it. My problem is the pointer `HUD` has invalid value. Of course i checked default `HUD` of `GameMode`. What can i do for get valid value of `APlayerController::GetHUD`?

I just follow the step below to run `ClientRPCInitializeHud`.

1. Run `PlayerController`'s function on button event in Widget Blueprint .
2. Run `ServerRPCSpawnAsPlayableCharacter` function
3. Run `ClientRPCInitializeHud` function after call `APlayerController::Possess(SpawnedCharacter)`.

Here is the code.

```
 void AFpsPlayerController::OnSelectedTeam(EPlayerTeam team, TSubclassOf<class AFpsCharacter> CharacterClass, FTransform SpawnTransform)
 {
     ServerRPCSetTeam(team);
     ServerRPCSpawnAsPlayableCharacter(CharacterClass, SpawnTransform);
 }
 
 void AFpsPlayerController::ServerRPCSpawnAsPlayableCharacter_Implementation(TSubclassOf<AFpsCharacter> CharacterClass, FTransform SpawnTransform)
 {
     FActorSpawnParameters SpawnParameters;
     AFpsCharacter *SpawnedCharacter = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AFpsCharacter>(CharacterClass, SpawnTransform.GetLocation(), SpawnTransform.GetRotation().Rotator(), SpawnParameters);
     SpawnedCharacter->SetSpawnTransform(SpawnTransform);
     Possess(SpawnedCharacter);
     SpawnedCharacter->OnPossess();
 }
 
 void AFpsCharacter::OnPossess()
 {
     ClientRPCInitializeHud();
 }
```

I tried to check GetPlayerController(0)->GetHUD is valid or not if is called at Level Blueprint or Widget Blueprint but it is also invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is the default HUD instance isn't created by default HUD class of `GameMode`. I don't know well why it is happened even i checked default HUD class in `GameMode`. So i choose temporary solution. Using `APlayerController::ClientSetHUD(TSubclass<AHUD>)`. In my case, each `ACharacter` has `TSubclassOf<AHUD>` and run `APlayerController::ClientSetHUD(TSubclass<AHUD>)` at `APlayerController::OnPossess(APawn* InPawn)`.